# Seemingly straightforward recursive function ends in infinite loop

Tags: python, recursion

I have written the following code:

```
def incr_num(x, y):
    while x <= y:
        print x
        incr_num(x+1, y)
```

When I invoke this as

```
incr_num(1, 10)
```

it gets into an infinite loop and gives this output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
10
10
10
10
10
10

(number 10 keeps repeating)
```

I was expecting it to print numbers 1-10. I am not able to understand why it doesn't. Can someone please tell me why this happens.

I'm using python2.7.

Comment: Because you never change `x`, so the `while x <= y` is always true.

Comment: Infinite recursion, or infinite while loop?

Comment: use if instead of while

Comment: Brilliant title. Cricket nailed it, of course.

Comment: What *should* the output be?

Comment: @cricket_007: Can't it be both?

Comment: @Scott Ha. Python has Stackoverflow for indefinite recursion, so this is infinite loop

Comment: Note, in this case, *recursion is your looping structure*, so you probably have no need for the `while` loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct version would be:

```
def incr_num(x, y):
    if x <= y:
        print x
        incr_num(x+1, y)
```

Note that x is printed at most once for each recursive function call.

UPDATE:
The reason your function doesn't work is that `incr_num(10,10)` prints 10 and then calls `incr_num(11,10)`, which immediately returns. After this, `incr_num(10,10)` continues. It does not break out of the `while` loop and continues through with the next iteration, printing `10` and calling `incr_num(11,10)` again. As you can see, this cycle does not end.

Comment: How do you know this is the correct version, since OP didn't state what the expected result should be?

Comment: @ScottHunter The question, it seems to me is just to know why the program is not terminating.

Comment: There are many ways to make a program terminate; not many of the are correct.

Comment: My assumption is that the OP wants to recursively print integers in the range `[x,y]`.

Comment: I see that OP has updated the question - he did expect it to print numbers 1 to 10.

Answer (score 4):

`incr_num(x+1, y)` keeps getting called until `x == y`, and then  the recursion ends, then you return to the previous execution where `x=9`, so  `x`  still has the value it's passed, and `x <= y` is not False. Therefore the recursion happens again and prints 10

You'll at least  want a `x+=1` after that recursive call.

I wouldn't call a while loop inside recursion straightforward ;) If that's your base case for ending the recursion, you want `if x<=y`

Answer (score 4):

If your loop executes forever, it must mean the condition `x <= y` is always `True`. Consider this:

```
while x <= y:
    print x
```

It's a simplified version of your code, but that is essentially what you're doing.

Try:

```
def incr_num(x, y):
    if x <= y:
        print x
        incr_num(x+1, y)
```

This prints the numbers `1` through `10`.

Comment: I won't suggest to remove *while* loop, instead increment **x** before calling `incr_num`.

Answer (score 3):

Your condition  should be a if condition instead of a while loop because you are not changing the value of x within the while loop and Everytime the condition becomes true and makes a recursive call.

Here is a corrected version of it

```
def incr_num(x, y):
        if x <= y:
            print x
            incr_num(x+1, y)
```